# Marketing Cloud SQL - Can we do maths using field values

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

I have a scenario which I want to understand if it's possible

1. I need to pull all contacts which are in a 'waitlist' where a matched property has a status of Available (all good so far)
2. Where it gets harder is, I need to limit the amount of records pulled by the amount of available spaces x 2.

Is there a way that I can say something like (pull amount = [field value] x 2) - essentially giving me only the amount of records I need, being specified in a specific field.

just to make it harder - there can be lots of waiting lists in this one query, So i would need for example, only 10 contacts with property a linked, but i might need 20 if they're linked to property b...

Answer (score 3):

If you number all of the records on the waitlist, then you can definitely just select that many results.

Something like this:

**Sample data**

```sql
CREATE TABLE waitlist (
     waitlistId int,
     numSlots int
);
CREATE TABLE waitlistMember (
     waitlistId int,
     subscriberKey varchar(254),
     status varchar(15),
     insertedDate datetime default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
);

INSERT INTO waitlist
     (waitlistId, numSlots)
VALUES
      ('1111', 2)
    , ('2222', 3)

INSERT INTO waitlistMember
     (waitlistId, subscriberKey, status)
VALUES
  (1111, 'sk6', 'available')
, (1111, 'sk7', 'available')
, (1111, 'sk3', 'nope')
, (1111, 'sk1', 'available')
, (1111, 'sk4', 'available')
, (1111, 'sk5', 'available')
, (1111, 'sk8', 'nope')
, (1111, 'sk2', 'available')
, (2222, 'sk1', 'available')
, (2222, 'sk5', 'available')
, (2222, 'sk2', 'available')
, (2222, 'sk7', 'nope')
, (2222, 'sk8', 'available')
, (2222, 'sk3', 'available')
, (2222, 'sk6', 'available')
, (2222, 'sk4', 'available')
;
```

**Query**

```sql
select
  x.subscriberKey
, x.status
, x.waitListId
, x.insertedDate
, x.rowNum
, l.numSlots
from (
     select 
       m.subscriberKey
     , m.status
     , m.waitListId
     , m.insertedDate
     , row_number() over (partition by m.waitlistid order by m.insertedDate) rowNum
     from waitlistMember as m
     where 1=1
     and m.status = 'available'
) x
inner join waitlist as l on l.waitlistId = x.waitlistId
where 1=1
and x.rowNum <= l.numSlots * 2
```

**Output**

| subscriberKey | status | waitListId | insertedDate | rowNum | numSlots |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sk6 | available | 1111 | 2023-05-18 11:51:58.360 | 1 | 2 |
| sk7 | available | 1111 | 2023-05-18 11:51:58.360 | 2 | 2 |
| sk1 | available | 1111 | 2023-05-18 11:51:58.360 | 3 | 2 |
| sk4 | available | 1111 | 2023-05-18 11:51:58.360 | 4 | 2 |
| sk1 | available | 2222 | 2023-05-18 11:51:58.360 | 1 | 3 |
| sk5 | available | 2222 | 2023-05-18 11:51:58.360 | 2 | 3 |
| sk2 | available | 2222 | 2023-05-18 11:51:58.360 | 3 | 3 |
| sk8 | available | 2222 | 2023-05-18 11:51:58.360 | 4 | 3 |
| sk3 | available | 2222 | 2023-05-18 11:51:58.360 | 5 | 3 |
| sk6 | available | 2222 | 2023-05-18 11:51:58.360 | 6 | 3 |

Try/tweak it for yourself: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/k2fYLrSl)

The inner query does the numbering and then the outer query uses the results to match on the constraints.

Comment: Great, thanks for this - I'll give it a go